# I want to take the variable that contains a mysql query from one php file, and write the loop that will print the query contents in another php file

Tags: php, mysql, function

I am a beginner trying to make a webpage where a schedule of reservations is being retrieved from the database. In a php file I have a class that has a function that creates a query using a SELECT statement, here is the function

```
public function getDTodayScheduleDB(){

             $session=Modulator::getSession();
             $session->start();
             $currentdrID=$_SESSION['userID'];

             $todayDate = date("Y/m/d");

             $getTSchedule = "SELECT time, user.name FROM reservation FULL JOIN user ON childID = user.ID AND doctorID = '$currentdrID'  AND date = '$todayDate'";
             $result = Modulator::getDb()->query($getTSchedule); 
             return $result;
        }
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to do it or not but I read this when I tried googling it. the $result variable is returned in a php file and used like this

```
<?php

                include realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Classes/Models/DoctorModel.php');
                $scheduleResult = DoctorModel::getDTodayScheduleDB();
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($scheduleResult)){
                    $appTime = $row['time'];
                    $childName = $row['name'];





                    echo"<tr>";
                    echo"<td>".$appTime."</td>";
                    echo"<td>".$childName."</td>";
                    echo"</tr>";
                }
             ?>
```

However I do not know why it is not working although I tested the query elsewhere and it works so he problem is with the variable passing from the function to the other page I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `::` operator, you are calling a non static (i.e instance method) function as if it was a static function. Assuming that your getDTodayScheduleDB is inside a DoctorModel class, you have to define it this way:

```
public static function getDTodayScheduleDB(){
   //your code here 
}
```